# ¿Cómo Instalar correctamente JavaCC en Linux?

Tags: java, linux, javacc

Estoy intentando instalar *JavaCC* en mi Raspberry Pi OS (derivado de Debian) siguiendo los pasos que se muestran en el sitio oficial de [javacc.github.io](https://javacc.github.io/javacc/#download), pero las instrucciones no son claras para mi.

Entiendo hasta el `$ tar xvf javacc-7.0.11.tar.gz`, pero desde ahí estoy perdido puesto que menciona que el binario `javacc-7.0.11.jar` se tiene que mover a una carpeta `target/` seguido de renombrarlo a "javacc.jar", y entonces agregar la carpeta `scripts/` (del descomprimido) al $PATH.

Debo mencionar algunas cosas, empezando con que no encuentro ningun binario dentro del descomprimido que se llame "javacc-7.0.11.jar", solamente encuentro un archivo en bootstrap/ que de hecho se llama "javacc.jar", pero como no se menciona en las instrucciones, no lo toco. También debo mencionar que no tengo idea de qué se habla cuando se dice algo de una carpeta `target/`, ergo, no tengo idea de qué hacer con este susodicho binario "javacc.jar".

Lo que sí pude hacer es agregar el `scripts/` al $PATH, pero al intentar ejecutar JavaCC en la consola sale lo siguiente:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class javacc
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javacc
```

Esto me hace pensar que el paso que me falta es saber dónde poner el dicho archivo `javacc.jar`.

¿Hay algún paso que no esté siguiendo correctamente, que no haya visto o que me haya saltado? ¿Los pasos en el sitio están incompletos?

NOTA: Encontré que el `javacc-7.0.11.jar` está a un lado de la descarga de los comprimidos (lo cual me parece raro que estén por separados), pero aún así me falta saber dónde es ese dicha carpeta `target/`.

NOTA 2: No hace ninguna diferencia el `chmod +x scripts/javacc` sugerido para sistemas UNIX.

Comment: Buenas, paso a aclarar. Si bajaste el TAR, es el source code, no los binarios "jar" en si. tenes que bajar el que dice "Binaries" (te baja el jar directamente). Luego el jar los podes colocar en donde la maquina virtual busca los binarios por defecto ($CLASSPATH), o incluso en el mismo directorio de paquetes de tu proyecto, ya que java si no lo encuentra en CLASSPATH,  va a buscar en los directorios de tu proyecto. Saludos